# Document Information Panel issue

Tags: managed-metadata, dip

The problem we have is that for custom content types not all managed metadata column are displayed in Document Information Panel (DIP) for the document in MS Office client application. 
However, everything works fine if there is only one content type with managed metadatafields in the library.

We have found bad workaround that doesn't suit to us. But anyway...
If we remove MM column from list and readd it then everything works fine for existed in the list content types, but if we add new custom CT to the list, for newly added we have an issue again.